# 502 Bad Gateway on reverse proxy nodejs using Nginx with https

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I've seen similar questions like this asked a lot but the errors they're getting don't seem to be a 502 bad gateway just an issue with setting up the server.

So I'm running a `nodejs` application using `pm2` to keep the process running.

In my `nginx` `/sites-available/default` file I have...

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl     on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.name.comfullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.name.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:4444;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

        location /demo {
            proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:4444;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

So I've got my certificate setup and I can hit my server on `https` and see everything i've placed in the `index.html` file. Within the `index.html` file there's a `<a href="https://server.name.com/demo">Link</a>` that forwards me to `/demo` where in my `location` block I'm trying to proxy the port `4444` which my application is running on.

I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error when I hit the page.

I'm a bit lost on the steps to debug this. Any help?

Comment: You should look at the error log (usually in `/var/log/nginx/`), and perhaps try `127.0.0.1:4444` rather than `0.0.0.0:4444`.

Answer (score 0):

Is on 0.0.0.0:4444 realy a https service running and not http? Anyway i would recommend not to use ssl behind the reverese-proxy because of performance issues and there is no need for encryption.